# Choosing word from dictionary from context menu (using Enter key) submits the comment

Tags: bug, comments

I often choose correct word spelling from browser's built-in dictionary.

When writing a comment and choosing correct word from context menu using <kbd>Enter</kbd> key submits the comment.

I do not want this behavior.

This is good to submit comment on <kbd>Enter</kbd> but not when it is pressed in context menu.