# Master duplicate question missing (deleted?)

Tags: support, duplicate-questions

Looking if a certain site problem was already reported (asked as a question) I found it, opened it, and it was marked as a duplicate of another question, that also had 2 answers. But when trying to open that other question, I get a page saying it was deleted.

I don't see the purpose of marking a question as closed/duplicate with linked question erased. Either the first (the alleged duplicate) question should be reopened or also deleted (it is a guess, as I don't know the reason of deleting the other).

The question is [Choosing word from dictionary from context menu (using Enter key) submits the comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173785/choosing-word-from-dictionary-from-context-menu-using-enter-key-submits-the-co)

Answer (score 3):

You are right. The duplicate question was deleted, so in fact the question that was closed as a duplicate of that one can be reopened. (The question was deleted by a moderator / community manager of SE, I am not sure why)

I casted by reopen vote. Hope it gets reopened and answered / fixed!

Comment: OK, should I follow the advice on the page saying "If those answers do not fully address your question, please ask a new question." (and post a new question), or not? Should I just post the already written one and pretend I did not see your answer? ;)

Comment: I undeleted the original. Not sure why it was deleted.

Comment: Shouldn't the site prevent deleting questions that are pointed to as duplicates? Or delete and automatically "unduplicate"?

Comment: I agree with you. Maybe it is proposed already. Not sure. Will take a look.

Comment: @David what about this one? http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/169201/245360