# Comment box submits when enter key is used for browser menus

Tags: bug, comments

(note: a similar questions was asked already, but it lacks detail and is closed currently: [Choosing word from dictionary from context menu (using Enter key) submits the comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173785/choosing-word-from-dictionary-from-context-menu-using-enter-key-submits-the-co) )

A when a user starts typing a comment and then uses the enter key to use the browser menus, the comment is submitted.

Example:

- start typing a comment
- press alt , left  , up , enter (to select the About item in Firefox menu)

Result:

- Firefox about dialog appears
- comment is submitted

The comment should not be submitted.
It happens with other menus (also context menus of the text area) too, and other browsers (also tested with IE11 and Chrome - in Chrome the issue does not happen, while in IE it happened once, then on the second try it didn't).

Comment: This does not seem to happens any more (using Firefox 40.0.3)... oh it still does in some cases ... :-p